# I am trying to implement a max count function within my 'click counter' android app

Tags: java, android

So far I have the below java code.  I am new to java.  I would like to be able to have a max count of 500 after which the count returns to '0' and you can start counting again.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class wazeefa extends Activity
{
    TextView txtCount;
    Button btnCount;
    int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wazeefa);

        //button sound
        final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.countbutton);

        txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wcount);
        txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        btnCount = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wclick);

        btnCount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View V)
            {
                count++;
                txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                mpButtonClick.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class wazeefa extends Activity{

TextView txtCount;
Button btnCount;
int count = 0;  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wazeefa);

    //button sound
    final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.countbutton);

    txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wcount); 
    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    btnCount = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wclick);       

    btnCount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View V) {
            count++; 
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            mpButtonClick.start();

            if (count >= 500) {
               count = 0;
            }
        }
        });
}}
```

Comment: in the text i found `max count of 500 after which the count returns to '0'`, i thought 500 is inclusive

Comment: you're right. You're interpretation and solution of the question seems valid.

Comment: I used this answer, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Use the % ([modolus / reminder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation)) operator.

```
count = (count + 1) % 500; //count will be in range [0,499] inclusive
```

Or if you want to allow 500 as well:

```
count = (count + 1) % 501; //count will be in range [0,500] inclusive
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(count > 500) {
    count = 0;
}
```

This is the if statement, and basically the code inside the brackets will only be carried out if whatever it says at the top is true. It is the bread and butter of programming, and if you're new to java your code isn't half bad

Comment: Remember to hit answer on the answer you thought was the most helpful, so the question is closed, and welcome to stack overflow :D